# Low quality posts from high rep users

Tags: discussion, feature-request, answer-quality, review

Why do posts from people with >50k reputation show up in the Low Quality queue?

Would it not make sense to have a filter where answers from users with more than `$arbitrary_high_number` reputation do not appear in that queue?

For example, I just had to review [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/151344/6761); the risk of one of Stéphane's answers failing to meet the standards expected here is vanishingly small, it it exists at all...

Comment: That would of course vastly reduce anyone else's chances to get the Steward badge on the [LQPRQ](http://unix.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/stats)

Comment: @Anthon I'm not sure I follow your line of reasoning.

Comment: I was exaggerating a bit by using the word 'vastly', but I have reviewed Stéphane's answers on this queue on a regular basis. (I haven't counted them but I would think at least 25). Reducing the numbers of items that pop up on the LQPRQ would diminish peoples' chances for gaining review queue related badges.

Comment: @Anthon: oh, I see now. His answers are only ever in there for their brevity, though. There *are* plenty of genuinely low quality posts to go round...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They show up there purely due to their length (being too short). His answers are often just code with no explanations, so they often fall into this category, and I regularly have to approve them as OK too.

I agree that it seems ridiculous, but I'm not sure how well received making a change to that automated audit will be. We can ask the higher ups to see what they have to say about it as well.

#### EDIT #1

So the preliminary read on this is as I had imagined it. Other mods and SE staff are chiming in saying that being high rep doesn't make one exempt to producing crap A's, so the VLQ audit is unlikely to change. We can pursuit it further, but I don't see this mindset changing with any amount of discussions or time.

Comment: If they have code with no explanation, I would argue they **should** appear in the Low Quality queue, no? While they may be good answers, a new or newish user may need the explanation to go with it.

Comment: @RoryAlsop - this is why I just approve his A's when the show up in the VLQ, and have not pursued it further. It's only with jason asking that I'm asking the higher ups what their thoughts are on the subject. There's a gray area here and Stephane's A's are definitely in it.

Comment: Stephane's A's are often 110% correct, but are often a code drop. Take them for what they are. I've taken them and expanded them purely for my own benefit and others, but I have not done this of late since I know I can do it when/if I need to, and I have limited bandwidth.

Comment: Yep - that makes sense.

Comment: Thanks for looking into it. I was asking because, as the site gets busier, the signal to noise will decrease and one way to manage that would be to make some tweaks to the performance of the janitorial tasks, but if the wisdom and experience from the older and larger sites shows it to be unnecessary, so be it.

Answer (score 6):

Whenever you are in the Low Quality Review Queue, **you are evaluating the quality of the post, not of the user.** If the post needs improvements and you can improve it, please do so. If only the author can do those improvements, you should comment asking for elaboration and select recommend deletion. If you are not sure, just hit skip.

Reputation should not be a measure of quality of the posts, most contrary, high reputation users set the example to the community and should be the higher quality possible.

Comment: I agree, but the likelihood of anyone here with >50K producing a crap answer is so low as to be zero, and yet someone has to review the post. Over time, that is just a wasted click, IMO.

Comment: @jasonwryan if any of my post end in the LQRQ, please inform me. I will improve it. Also, remember that NAA's and VLQ flags are feed to the queue.

Comment: Sure, happy to. I doubt that high rep users' answers are getting flagged, though. :)

Comment: +5 I could not agree more